# How to select the nth column of a bigquery table with no aliases?

Tags: google-bigquery

```
sh-3.2$ bq shell
Welcome to BigQuery! (Type help for more information.)
bqaccount> select 1;
Waiting on bqjob_r42d56b0f0c2a3eb9_00000164b439b383_1 ... (0s) Current status: DONE
+-----+
| f0_ |
+-----+
|   1 |
+-----+
bqaccount> select f0_ from (select 1);
Error in query string: Error processing job 'bqaccount:bqjob_r7d8d3d2925de7c0c_00000164b439def3_1': Unrecognized name: f0_ at [1:8]
```

Is there any way to select a specific column from a query that has no aliases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can cast as a struct with a name for the column:

```
SELECT CAST(t AS STRUCT<f0_ INT64, f1_ INT64, f2_ INT64>).f0_
FROM (SELECT 1, 2, 3) AS t
```

Answer (score 3):

Referencing fn_ is possible with BigQuery Legacy SQL

```
#legacySQL
SELECT f2_, f0_, f1_
FROM (SELECT 1, 2, 3)
```

result is

```
Row f2_ f0_ f1_  
1   3   1   2
```

Looks like it is not supported in BigQuery Standard SQL though

So, below is one of a workaround for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  cols[OFFSET(0)],
  cols[OFFSET(1)],
  cols[OFFSET(2)],
  cols[OFFSET(3)],
  cols[OFFSET(4)]
FROM (SELECT 1, 2, 3, 'abc', CURRENT_DATE()) t, 
UNNEST([
  STRUCT<cols ARRAY<STRING>>(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(TO_JSON_STRING(t), r'"[^"]?":"?(\w*)"?'))
])
```

or another version of the very same approach (whatever you will find better looking for you)

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  cols[OFFSET(0)],
  cols[OFFSET(1)],
  cols[OFFSET(2)],
  cols[OFFSET(3)],
  cols[OFFSET(4)]
FROM (
  SELECT REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(TO_JSON_STRING(t), r'"[^"]?":"?(\w*)"?') cols
  FROM (SELECT 1, 2, 3, 'abc', CURRENT_DATE()) t
)
```

with result

```
Row f0_ f1_ f2_ f3_ f4_  
1   1   2   3   abc 2018
```

Comment: Nice one! If you want to select all rows where the first col isn't `null` (as I did) you can simplify to `WHERE REGEXP_EXTRACT(TO_JSON_STRING(t), r'{"[^"]+":("?\w*"?)') <> 'null'`

Comment: Mine could be improved with `REGEXP_CONTAINS` to check for `null`, but anyway - many thanks for the idea of using json string. Just another minor point ... the values can contain more than just "word" chars ... your solution could be extended to use `[^"]*` in the value portion like you did with the key (if it's within quotes).

Answer (score 0):

I think the first ? in...

SELECT REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(TO_JSON_STRING(t), r'"[^"]?":"?(\w*)"?') cols

...should be a * or +